# When given ODE has a complex solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I consider the following ODE
$$
f''(x) + \frac{1}{cx} f'(x) - \frac{1}{bcx} f(x) = 0
$$
for some constant $b$ and $c$.

From https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html, I know that its solution has the form
$$y(x)=A\:x^{\frac{c-1}{2c}}I_{1-\frac{1}{c}}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{bc}}x^{1/2}\right)+B\:x^{\frac{c-1}{2c}}I_{-1+\frac{1}{c}}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{bc}}x^{1/2}\right)\quad\text{for} \quad 1-\frac{1}{c}\notin \mathbb{Z}.$$
where $A,B$ are some constant.

Then, I substituted $\frac{4}{3}$ and checked in WolframAlpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%27%27+%2B+1%2F%284%2F3+x%29+f%27+-+1%2F%28b+4%2F3+x%29+f+%3D+0) what is the solution. It returned
$$
f(x) = \frac{3^{\frac{1}{8}}c_1x^{\frac{1}{8}} \Gamma(\frac{3}{4}) I_{-\frac{1}{4}}(\frac{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{b}})}{2^{\frac{1}{4}}b^{\frac{1}{8}}} + \frac{(-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}3^{\frac{1}{8}} c_2 x^\frac{1}{8} \Gamma(\frac{5}{4}) I_{\frac{1}{4}}(\frac{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{b}})}{2^{\frac{1}{4}} b^{\frac{1}{8}}}.
$$
The second component of the above sum is complex (because $(-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}$).

My question is:

1. Why in this case the solution has a complex component while the general form of solution (given above) does not have it>
2. Are there any special cases (for given $b$ or $c$) when the solution has a complex component like in this case. I found that for $c=\frac{3}{4}$ both components of the sum are real.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the full term you should see that you have a free constant $c_2$ as a factor in that product. Now you can combine these constants $(-1)^{1/4}c_2$ into a new constant resp. compensate the complex factor by a conjugate factor in $c_2$.

---

Note that Mathematica/ WA is an CAS, not a computer calculus system. Following that origin, it interprets any given problem in the complex domain (algebraically closed domain) and thus does no clean-up for complex terms in its results. There may be a hidden option for WolframAlpha to  change that behavior so that it returns purely real solutions that satisfy the problem in real calculus terms.

Comment: Ok, do I understand properly that there can be either real or complex solutions to the given equations?  I thought that parameters $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be only real. From your response I understand that they can be also complex. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, in the results of WA any free variable is to be considered complex.

Comment: Thank you. So if I am interested only in real solutions, I should consider real parameters $A$ and $B$ in the first equation and not focus on the second form.

Comment: Yes, use the first form. All these extra constant factors in the second case are the result of the internal solution process, perhaps even following a different path than in the first general case.